# Facebook Access token extension

Tags: java, facebook

I have an access token with an expiry of 2 months and i want to extend the token every time i access it. Please give me any way paid or unpaid to do the same.

I tried with this code:

```
AccessToken accessTokenTT = 
                  new  DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_5).obtainExtendedAccessToken(appID,
                          appSecret, accessToken);
facebookClient25 = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessTokenTT.getAccessToken(), Version.VERSION_2_5);
dtInfo = facebookClient25.debugToken(accessTokenTT.getAccessToken());
System.out.println(dtInfo.getExpiresAt());
```

the `accessToken` used here is the one that is already extended to 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t extend/refresh it just by using the Token. You can only refresh it on user interaction - meaning, the user has to revisit your App. Else, it would be pointless to create Tokens that are only valid for 2 months. If a user did not use your App for 2 months, you should not be able to use his Token anymore.

Only App Tokens and Extended Page Tokens are valid forever. Try to use those, you can´t programmatically extend other ones.

Comment: Sorry i ask my question in a wrong way. My actual intention is to get the solution of this problem: "I use my access token to get the share counts of public urls. But after expiry of the access token, we manually get the new access tokens. I want to do this task pragrammatically to get the new access token. If it would not be possible, is there any other way to access the share counts of public urls".

Comment: added more information about that in my answer. just use an app token.